# Oracle cusor return result and get value by dynamic column name

Tags: oracle, plsql, for-in-loop

As tittle, I want to get value by column name as paramater in cursor result.

I could not find the answer after searching a long time,Could anybody give some help?

```
--common usage
BEGIN
    for rowValue in (select code, name from tableA)
    LOOP
     -- rowValue.code  rowValue.name
    END LOOP;
END


BEGIN
    FOR rowValue IN (select * from tableA)
    LOOP
        -- tableB will keep some column's names about talbeA
        FOR columnNames IN (select name from tableB)
        LOOP
         -- want to use like:  rowValue.(columnNames.name)
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END
```

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. What's the reason behind wanting to do it?

Comment: You can probably do it with dynamic SQL - see [dbms_sql](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sql.htm) - but it won't be pretty, and does sound like a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DBMS_SQL, like this:

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor                INTEGER;
  l_column_count          INTEGER;
  l_column_descriptions   SYS.DBMS_SQL.desc_tab;
  l_column_value          VARCHAR2 (4000);
  l_status                INTEGER;

  TYPE col_map_tab_type IS TABLE OF INTEGER
    INDEX BY VARCHAR2 (30);

  col_map_tab             col_map_tab_type;
BEGIN
  l_cursor   := sys.DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;

  -- parse SQL
  sys.DBMS_SQL.parse (c => l_cursor, statement => 'SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE ROWNUM <= 10', language_flag => sys.DBMS_SQL.native);

  -- Describe columns
  sys.DBMS_SQL.describe_columns (c => l_cursor, col_cnt => l_column_count, desc_t => l_column_descriptions);

  FOR i IN 1 .. l_column_count LOOP
    col_map_tab (l_column_descriptions (i).col_name)   := i;
    DBMS_SQL.define_column (l_cursor,
                            i,
                            l_column_value,
                            4000);
  END LOOP;

  l_status   := sys.DBMS_SQL.execute (l_cursor);

  WHILE (sys.DBMS_SQL.fetch_rows (l_cursor) > 0) LOOP
    FOR column_names IN (SELECT column_name
                         FROM   dba_tab_columns
                         WHERE  table_name = 'DBA_OBJECTS'
                         AND    column_name LIKE 'O%') LOOP
      DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (l_cursor, col_map_tab (column_names.column_name), l_column_value);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (column_names.column_name || ' = ' || l_column_value);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  sys.DBMS_SQL.close_cursor (l_cursor);
END;
```

Comment: You could use another `col_map_tab` to store the target column names, instead of requerying with `FOR column_names IN ...` for each row you fetch from the main query. (In this demo the first reference to DBA_OBJECTS` is the OP's table A, and the second is table B, right?)

Comment: Yes, I just worried about the low performance using dynamic SQL by DBMS_SQL,(TableA has more than two hundred thousand rows). I will test it.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes -- but I wanted to keep the example structured somewhat close to the OP's initial code.  Actually, instead of a 2nd `col_map_tab`, I'd probably just loop through the one I had and remove any that weren't in Table B (DBA_TAB_COLUMNS, in my example).  Then, just iterate over `col_map_tab` as the inner loop.